# Error starting system-config-printer

Tags: drivers, printing

I've installed EPSON printer drivers using the command line, and now I am unable to start the printer config.  Follows is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/system-config-printer.py", line 29, in <module>
    import dbus
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    import dbus.types as types
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/types.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _dbus_bindings import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_dbus_bindings'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/system-config-printer/system-config-printer.py", line 29, in <module>
    import dbus
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    import dbus.types as types
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/types.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _dbus_bindings import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_dbus_bindings'
```

I have used

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center python-dbus
sudo apt-get install python3-dbus python3-dbus.mainloop.qt
```

but am still getting the error.

Comment: I found the problem.  I had installed python 3.6 and set /usr/bin/python3 to it.  Changing  /usr/bin/python3 back to python 3.5 solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I had installed python 3.6 and set /usr/bin/python3 to it. Changing /usr/bin/python3 back to python 3.5 solved the problem.

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python3

sudo ln -s python3.5 /usr/bin/python3
```